# Error trying to loop Observable Object in Angular 2

Tags: json, http, angular, typescript, observable

I'm stuck here trying to loop the observable object on my users service. 
The Chrome's console throws:

> error_handler.js:47 EXCEPTION: undefined is not a function

Here's my code:

users.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../user.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { User } from '../user';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.css']
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {

 people: Observable<User[]>;
  constructor( private _userService: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
        this.people = this._userService.getAll();
        console.log(this.people);
    }
}
```

users.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { ErrorObservable } from 'rxjs/observable/ErrorObservable';
import { User } from './user';


@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  private baseurl: string= 'http://swapi.co/api';

  constructor(private http: Http) { 
      console.log("User service initialized");
  }


  getAll(): Observable<User[]>{
    let users$ = this.http
      .get(`${this.baseurl}/people`,{headers: this.getHeaders()})
      .map(this.mapUsers);

      return users$;
  }


  private getHeaders(){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    return headers;
  }


  mapUsers(response: Response): User[]{
       return response.json().results.map(this.toUser);
  }


  toUser(r:any): User{
    let user = <User>({
        id: this.extractId(r),
        name: r.name
    });
    console.log('Parsed user'+user.name);
    return user;
  }


extractId(personData:any){
    let extractedId = personData.url.replace('http://swapi.co/api/people/','').replace('/','');
    return parseInt(extractedId);
}

}
```

users.component.html

```
<ul class="people">
    <li *ngFor="let person of people | async " >
        <a href="#">
          {{person.name}}
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

user.ts

```
export interface User{
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
```

When I remove the HTML code from the template, everything works great (no errors on console) so, I guess there's something wrong with 'people' object, and obviously I can't iterative the response. Please guys, a hand would be appreciated here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely reason is the way you are handling the `map` callback

```
getAll(): Observable<User[]>{
  let users$ = this.http
    .get(`${this.baseurl}/people`,{headers: this.getHeaders()})
    .map(this.mapUsers);
}

mapUsers(response: Response): User[]{
  return response.json().results.map(this.toUser);
}

toUser() {}
```

You need to be careful when using `this` inside callback functions. The context  sometimes messes you up. In this case `this` in `.map(this.toUser)` does not point to the class instance. You need to bind it, i.e.

```
  let users$ = this.http
    .get(`${this.baseurl}/people`,{headers: this.getHeaders()})
    .map(this.mapUsers.bind(this));
```

When you use `bind(this)` you are saying that any uses of `this` inside the `mapUsers` function should be bound to the class instance.

When you use arrow functions, you don't need to worry about this distinction, as it keeps the lexical scope context

```
let users$ = this.http
  .get(`${this.baseurl}/people`,{headers: this.getHeaders()})
  .map(res => response.json().results.map(this.toUser));
```

Also, even passing the `toUser` function has the same problem, as you are using `this.extractId(r)`. You also need to bind that

```
mapUsers(response: Response): User[]{
  return response.json().results.map(this.toUser.bind(this));
}
```

Comment: Thank you pesskillet for yor reply. Good to know that..  I'll keep it on mind. I've modified the function, updating the map call: .map(this.mapUsers.bind(this)); ... but now the console throws:

Uncaught Error: Module build failed: Error: /home/webdeveloper/Workspace/Angular2/unibague_directory_v2/src/app/user.service.ts (26,14): Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<User[]>'.
  Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'User[]'.

Comment: And if I use the second option (res =>) my code editor (visual studio) underlines the "response" word. (variable not declared)

Comment: Well, yeah, it was a typo. It should be `response`, not `res`

Comment: Hey peeskillet, thank you very very much.. it works now. You made my day.